# Android - Show help to the user on how to use the application when launched for the first time

Tags: android

What is the best way to show help (or user guidelines) to the user when application is launched for the first time. Some applications show overlay text and arrows to inform about the various features available in the application. What is the best way to implement it ? Do I need separate activity or do I modify my homescreen xml or something else ?
Please suggest some good approch as well as specific query to search on google (I couldn't find any specific result on Google)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this lib and have a look at how it's done: https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView

> The ShowcaseView library is designed to highlight and showcase
>   specific parts of apps to the user with a distinctive and attractive
>   overlay. This library is great for pointing out points of interest for
>   users, gestures, or obscure but useful items.
>        The library is based on the "Cling" view found in the Launcher on Ice-Cream Sandwich and Jelly Bean, but extended to be easier to use.

Comment: Thanks @Waza_Be
This library works perfectly when I want to focus view components in xml. But my activity don't use any xml, rather all views are created in java class. Now when I'm trying to apply showcaseview, it's shown at the center all the time

Comment: I am not a heavy user of this lib, but I am pretty sure it can achieve what you want... Maybe you should contact the dev on github or create an separate SO question... I have shared what I knew.